# Need to allow '<' and '>' in textboxes without setting Validation Request=fale ASP.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, client-side-validation

I need some help in allowing the '<' and  '>' in textboxes, without setting validationRequest=false.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: ValidateRequest is a terrible hack. Why have it on?

Comment: I am not suppose to set ValidationRequest=false. But I have to allow '<' and '>' symbols in my textboxes. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You can use `Server.HtmlEncode(string) ` to encode user input

Comment: Take the advice from @Munawir .You should never allow raw html entities in user inputs. Imagine what a hacker can do when entering <script> tags etc.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET MVC *(which you should)*, you can mark a property of your model object with the `[AllowHtml]` attribute.

Comment: For texts in '<' and '>, I can add validation. But rest of the things should be accepted. @Munawir Please help me in this. Could you please explain me more about this. Where do we give server.HtmlEncode?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send it to server you can encode values on client side:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="encode();">
```

The JS function can look like:

```
function encode() {
    $("#myInput").val(window.escape($("#myInput").val()));
};
```

Comment: Could you explain me in detail.?

Comment: Onsubmit is an event which is called just before form is submitted to the serwer. I defined a function named encode() which will be executed when onsubmit event will fire. Inside that function I look for textbox which contains html markup and replace its text with encoded one - with the help of window.escape() function. That why serwer will get encoded text which you can decode after you will receive it.

Comment: #myInput is the textbox ID...?

Comment: Yes, myInput is the Id # is for JQuery and its a shortcut for selecting by Id.

Comment: I dont have have form in my page. I have given the onsubmit function on the button But it is not working :(

Comment: If you have your form in your master page you can find it with the help of jQuery $("#form-id").submit().